# Compiling project not working as expected

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm not sure what happened but my Flex project seems to exhibit some strange compiler behavior. Two weird things:

1) I have a file with a lot of static consts. Changing consts doesn't elicit a recompile, so I need to clean and recompile to see the effects of any changes.

2) After every clean I get a same error in one of my main files (a type coercion that in fact should not be an error). If I save that file with a slight change, i.e. if I start a recompile due to changes in that file, all goes fine.

Any thoughts on what could cause something like this and, more importantly, how to fix it?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Copiler errors on large projects especially when you've got a lot of `Embed`-s and `switch` operators are common. I've faced this many times and it is usually solved by some small change.

There are several concepts that I use to decrease the probability of such issues:

1. Do not use `switch`
2. [Do not use `[Embed(...)]` metatag in big projects](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/storing-icons-in-external-zip-and-seamless-work-with-composite-icons/)